# How to change the textColor of TextInput in react native dynamically?

Tags: react-native

hi guys i want to change textcolor of input dynamically. for example initially in CSS placed as color:'#fff',then i want to change the text color whenever need as '#ddd'.

Comment: What have you tried doing? Could you paste any code to help us see your project markup. I would personally store the color as a state variable and simply do `<TextInput style={{color: this.state.color}}/>`

Comment: This dynamic condition will be based on the state's value. Right ?

Comment: yes,  <TextInput style={{color: this.state.color}}/> its not working

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ternary operator` to check your condition. It has following format:
`(test conditon) ? true statement: false statement`

Based on that, you can set the `<TextInput>` `color` with something like this:

```
<TextInput
  style={[styles.input, (this.state.username ? styles.inputHighlight : null)]} //replace with your condition
/>
```

And add style stylesheet:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    //other styles
    color:'#fff'
  },
  inputHighlight: {
    color:'#ddd'
  }
});
```

Comment: style={[(this.state.checkSwitch ? styles.inputColor : styles.v_stInput)]} this is my condition checking switch  value based on that setting color but this is not working

Comment: <TextInput  
style={[(this.state.checkSwitch ? styles.inputColor : styles.v_stInput)]}/>

Comment: Are you sure that `this.state.checkSwitch` has your expected value? To check, add `{ console.log(this.state.checkSwitch) }` somewhere in your `render()`

Comment: thnks have found where i made mistake

Comment: Glad! :)
Mark this as correct ans/upvote if it was helpful :)

Comment: above ternary operator is helpful but that logic is not suitable for me so i approach another way.will share helpful to others.

Comment: oh sure..do share

Comment: I made a mistake what I  just tried to set the color state on TextInput property itself.Now I just set a color in switch condition.    toggleSwitch = (value) => {
        this.setState({ switchValue: value })

        let flag = this.state.switchValue;

        if (flag == false) {
            this.setState({ editable: true })
          
         
            this.setState({currentColor:'#353535'})




        } else if (flag == true) {
         
        
            this.setState({currentColor:'#ddd'})



        }
    }

Comment: No wonder, humans have this unique itch to make things harder, just to change the color, one has to write lines of code

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample app from expo to demonstrate dynamic color changes. I have used interval, but you can use as per your need with setColor function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { colors: '#ffffff' };
    }
    setColor = (value) => {
        this.setState({ colors: value })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let i = 0;
        let colorsArray = ['gray', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'pink', 'yellow']
        this._interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (i <= 5) {
                this.setColor(colorsArray[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={{ color: this.state.colors }}>
                    Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone!
          Save to get a shareable url. You get a new url each time you save.
        </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    },
});
```

Comment: The problem is TextInput, not Text. Can't do like that for TextInput in android

Comment: @TuanNguyen not sure if you had read the question or not, _hi guys i want to change textcolor of input dynamically._  and the above was working demo when I had posted my answer.

Comment: Which OS you built?

Comment: this demo was built and test in Android, but I had used similar kind of functionalities in both Android and iOS

Answer (score -1):

Similar to *Khushboo Shah*'s answer, this is how I adjusted the color for my `Component`. The code must be placed in the `render()` function, and `render()` must be triggered using normal methods.

```
render() {

    var overrideStyle = {};
    if ( condition ) {
         overrideStyle = { color: '#ddd' };
    }
    return (
              <Text style={[ this.props.style, overrideStyle ]}>
                //...
              </Text>
    );

}
```

Comment: Can't do that for TextInput in Android, but works in iOS man.